# Как отсортировать и сгруппировать по первому элементу?

Tags: mysql, sql

Использую MySql, пытаюсь получить лучшее значение в лучшей группировки и вернуть весь объект, написал:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM trainingobjects 
       ORDER BY SameIndex desc) t 
GROUP BY t.ApplicationUserId 
order by t.SameIndex desc
```

Не могу понять, почему возвращает не лучший результат, а другой.

Comment: дамп данных приложи

Comment: *Не могу понять, почему возвращает не лучший результат, а другой.* Непонятно, почему Вы полагаете, что запрос вообще должен работать. А если заставить его работать, отключив ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - непонятно, какой смысл ожидать от такого запроса хоть насколько-то осмысленного результата.

Comment: @Akina, А как тогда получить лучший результат после группировки?
Я хочу их сгруппировать и получить лучший результат по SameIndex.

Comment: @СергейВ., а как лучше вам дать данные через Insert для mysql?

Comment: @chilo5432 ага.

Comment: *А как тогда получить лучший результат после группировки?* Нет такого понятия как "лучший". Критерий должен оперировать числовыми значениями, а не субъективно-оценочными. Это может быть "максимальный", например - в таком случае нужен группирующий подзапрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку (пока, правда, задача неясна) должно быть что-то типа

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM trainingobjects t1
JOIN ( SELECT ApplicationUserId, MAX(SameIndex) SameIndex 
       FROM trainingobjects 
       GROUP BY ApplicationUserId ) t2 USING (ApplicationUserId, SameIndex)
ORDER BY t1.SameIndex desc
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло